# Binary arithmetic with unsigned numbers

Tags: binary-operations

I am struggling with performing binary math with unsigned numbers. I know I am supposed to take the 2s complement (flip the bits and add 1) of the subtrahend before I subtract, but for some reason my teacher marked me wrong on every single question I did.

Here is the question:

> Perform the following operations on the given numbers using the 2's
>   complement of the subtrahend (bottom number).
>
> The following numbers are UNSIGNED binary representations of the given
>   decimal number. Write the 2's complement of each number in the space
>   provided.
>   [image]

Like take A for example: If 0111 1010 is unsigned, then I make it a signed number by appending a sign bit in front of it. Right? Here is what I did for the first one:

> 122 = 1000 0101
>         +                          1
>             ________
>               1000 0110
>   -122 = 0000 0110 (by replacing the 1 with a zero on the rightmost bit)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You came up with $-122=00000110$, which is wrong. (You should recognize that as a representation of the number $+6$, whether the type is unsigned or not. The number $122$ in binary is (given as) $01111010$. The left bit is $0$, so $-122$ is representable as a signed $8$-bit integer. To find the binary representation  of $-122$, flip each bit of $01111010$ and add $1$. You did this, but then you went ahead and did something further. You should have stopped at $10000110$, which is the $8$-bit signed integer representation of $-122$.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually very helpful.